# Screaming shower head (the sequel)

Tags: shower, pipe, noise-reduction

See also [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3070/screaming-shower):

I recently soaked my Moen shower head in vinegar for a day to fix a problem where the center jets which pulsate were not working. Inside is an impeller of some kind and I assumed it was not spinning properly because of hard water buildup or lime, etc. Soaking in vinegar did the trick, the center jets are working better than ever.

But... the shrieking began. I looked up the above question but since I *just* cleaned the shower head, the answer is not satisfying.

So, how do I **stop** the shrieking? Is it time to get a new shower head? Will a more expensive one avoid this problem better?

Comment: Record it and start your own sound effects company :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another thing to try would be a slightly more aggressive cleaner than vinnegar - I've had good luck soaking the shower head in CLR, making sure to shake it up every few hours.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, shower heads are cheap, and easy to install. Your cleaning the old one fixed the impeller but made some other orifice just the right size to cause the screaming. The vinegar took away lime buildup, and I can't think of a way to quickly re-add the lime buildup in selected areas. Thus, buy a decent shower head, swap it in, and be done.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the restrictor washer in the head.

if you unscrew the head you can probably see it. You just need to enlarge it slightly to stop the vibration/squeal. Alternatively, just take it out.